# convert date to integer in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, integer

I'm trying to convert a date (date type) into int. This int should be something like the number of days since the 1 January 1900. How to get this in postgresql? In excel I'm getting this automatically when i concatenate a date with a string.
Example : 2011/11/01 convert into int as 36831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract the two dates:

```
select date '2011-11-01' - date '1900-01-01'
```

the result will be the number of days.

More details in the manual: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: One hundred years is roughly 36,500 days, right? So the OP's arithmetic works out to about 101 years between 1900 and 2011. I don't think I trust that answer. I'd much rather trust PostgreSQL's subtraction operator.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall': not sure which answer you mean with "not trust". But you are right: Postgres returns 40846 for my example

Comment: From OP: *"Example : 2011/11/01 convert into int as 36831"*

Comment: Thank you for the answer... But it's so confuse, in the excel, i can use this function: =datevalue("2011/11/01") for getting the serial number as 36831. But, in postgre... I tried the subtract as your answer, the result was not 36831 When i try this : (select date '2011-11-01' - date '1900-01-01') +2 in postgre, the result was same as 36831. Why it must add 2...i' m not sure with my query :-(

Comment: @nidazakiy Apparently Excel does **not** use `1900-01-01` as the base then. If you run `select date '2011-11-01' - 36831` you will see that this evaluates to `1910-12-30` so I guess that's what Excel is using . Btw: the name is either Postgres or PostgreSQL but **not** Postgre

Comment: Excel on Macs uses a different value for "beginning of time". But I don't think that alone could account for the difference here. @nidazakiy: Are you using a Mac?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Oke thank you..  I am sorry for my failure

Comment: @Mike : no, i am not using a Mac