# POSTGRESQL: how to convert date to integer?

Tags: postgresql, date, casting, integer

Within a plpgsql-function I have a simple insert statememt:

```
insert into table_Y (column1       ,
                     column2       ,
                     //more columns
                     int_date      , -- example: '20190714'
                     //more columns
                    )
select value1              ,
       value2              ,
       //more values
       date_value::integer ,
       //more values   
  from table_X
```

Column "date_value" in table table_X is of type date. Column int_date in table table_Y is of type integer ... so with the following expression:

```
date_value::integer
```

... I want to convert the value from column "date_value" to an integer (e.g. from 14. July 2019 to '20190714').

However, I'm getting the following error message:

```
ERROR:  cannot cast type date to integer
```

How can I convert the date to an integer instead?

P.S.: the solution to this question: [convert date to integer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557770/convert-date-to-integer-in-postgresql) does not help in my case becasue I don't want the number of days.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The direct conversion is not allowed, because usually has not sense - but you can use auxiliary conversion to text, and it should to work:

```
postgres=# SELECT to_char(CURRENT_DATE, 'YYYYMMDD')::integer;
┌──────────┐
│ to_char  │
╞══════════╡
│ 20190718 │
└──────────┘
(1 row)
```

But I have to say, so working with this representation of date is strange and unhappy.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `int` rather than `integer`, as following query worked for me:

```sql
SELECT * date_part('year/month/day', age(CURRENT_DATE,your date))::int
       as age
       from xyz_table
       where date_part('year/month/day', age(CURRENT_DATE,your date))::int > comparsion value ;
```