# POSTGRESQL convert date to unix timestamp int

Tags: sql, postgresql, alter-table, alter, alter-column

I have a table `matches` with a column `deleted_date` which is of type date, so its values look like `2020-12-30` right now. I want to change the type of this column from date to int so I can store unix timestamps instead.

I am trying to do so by running this command:

```
ALTER TABLE matches ALTER COLUMN deleted_date TYPE INT USING deleted_date::INT;
```

But running this command gives me the error:

```
 error: cannot cast type date to integer
```

Is there a way I can tell POSTGRESQL to just replace any deleted_by date values with a new empty 'null' integer var?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [convert date to integer in postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28557770/convert-date-to-integer-in-postgresql)

Comment: Also please note, that *its value looks like* has nothing about datatype or storage. It's a display task and you should always care of this task only at display time at application side.

Comment: Why? An integer is one of the worst possible datatypes for a date or timestamp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below alter statement for your requirement:

```
ALTER TABLE matches ALTER COLUMN deleted_date TYPE INT USING extract(epoch from deleted_date)::INT;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a timestamp (date + time) you should convert the column to a `timestamp` or even better  `timestamptz` type - do **not** use integers to store timestamps.

```
alter table matches alter deleted_date type timestamp
```